# How to define and use a list of string in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Trying to define a list of string variables in gitlab-ci.yml, which is required to be traversed inside a script.

Tried following syntax, but all failed with syntax error:

```
  script:
    - eks_namespaces = ( 'test1.yaml', 'test2.yaml' )


variables:
  eks_namespaces:  ( 'test1.yaml', 'test2.yaml' )

variables:
  eks_namespaces:  [ 'test1.yaml', 'test2.yaml' ]
```

eks_namespaces is going to be referred as :

```
  script:
    
    #!/bin/bash    
    - eks_namespaces = ( 'test1.yaml', 'test2.yaml' )
        
      for f in ${eks_namespaces}  
      .....
```

Is there any workaround to read an array of strings from a local file or any type of variable?

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Try creating your array with double-quotes and without comma's: `eks_namespaces=("test1.yaml" "test2.yaml")` in the `script` section.

Comment: tried but no luck. it's strange that gitlab-ci do not have array of strings

Comment: It's just a shell script that happens to be running in a docker container started by `gitlab-runner`. Anything you can do in a shell you can do in the `script` section, but which shell is used depends on the docker image you're using in your job.

Comment: using amazon/aws-cli base image. If running a script out of gitlab-ci.yml, script works and able to read each line and print values. But same code when kept under "script:" tag inside gitlab-ci yaml, it does not read any values from file.   using this script both in gitlab-ci and outside:                                                                           #!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; 
do
    echo "Text read from file: $line"
done < "$1"

Comment: I’ve edit your question and add the [bash] and/or [shell] tags to broaden the scope of people seeing your question. Also, can you edit it to provide your whole job definition from your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file?

Answer (score 7):

**Store multiple values in one variable**

It is not possible to create a CI/CD variable that is an array of values, but you can use shell scripting techniques for similar behavior.

For example, you can store multiple variables separated by a space in a variable, then loop through the values with a script:

```
job1:
  variables:
    FOLDERS: >
      src
      test
      docs
  script:
    - |
      for FOLDER in $FOLDERS
        do
          echo "The path is root/${FOLDER}"
        done
```

Source: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#store-multiple-values-in-one-variable